# 'int' object is not subscriptable on second iteration of loop when trying to convert a string item in a list to a list of integers

Tags: python, python-3.x, typeerror

I'm new to Python and I'm pretty confused as to why this part of my program is causing problems.

```
n = int(input())
c = []
l = []
i = 0
while(i<n):
    z = int(input())
    c.append(z)
    x = str(input())
    l.append(x)
    i += 1

listCount = 0

while(listCount < n ):
    binNumber = c[listCount]
    dataList = [int(n) for n in l[listCount].split()]        
    dataList.sort()
    listLength = len(dataList)
    lowestData = dataList[0]
    l = lowestData

    while( l <= dataList[listLength-1]):        
        intervalCounter = 0
        traverseCounter = 0

    while(traverseCounter < listLength):
        if(dataList[traverseCounter] >= l and dataList[traverseCounter] <= l + binNumber - 1):
            intervalCounter += 1
            traverseCounter += 1
        else:
            traverseCounter += 1        

        print( str(l) +'-'+ str(l + binNumber - 1) + ' ' + str(intervalCounter))
        l = l + binNumber
    print('\b')
    listCount += 1
```

The program outputs correctly on the first iteration of the loop but on the second or more iteration of the loop, it gives me this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "solution.py", line 21, in <module>
   dataList = [int(n) for n in l[listCount].split()]
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

Does first iteration of the loop change the code in any way to make it behave like this, I'm really confused as to how this works for the first loop but not the second.

The inputs are n test cases followed by 2 lines each first being the intervals and the second line being the values 
    input 
    2
    10
    36 25 38 46 55 68 72 55 36 38 67 45 22 48 91 46 52 61 58 55
    50
    2 2 1 255 0 3 4 5 6 7 200 100 10 50 0

This is how the output is supposed to be:

```
22-31 2
32-41 4
42-51 4
52-61 6
62-71 2
72-81 1
82-91 1

0-49 11
50-99 1
100-149 1
150-199 0
200-249 1
250-299 1
```

But all I get is:

```
22-31 2
32-41 4
42-51 4
52-61 6
62-71 2
72-81 1
82-91 1
```

Comment: Assuming it's pointing at `l`, there must be more code. I don't see any code here that makes `l` into an int. You also never change `n` or `listCount`, so the second loop will be infinite. Please show all the relevant code as an [mcve].

Comment: can you share the input and output

Comment: I've included the whole code, it's supposed to be a histogram

Comment: `l = lowestData` makes `l` a number, but you had it as a list before. Use more descriptive names and you won't accidentally overwrite old variables like that.

Comment: And in the future, please make sure you include all the relevant information from the start. Don't make it difficult for us to help you.

Comment: Thank you so much people, I'll try be more relevant the next time I post!!